# Communicating with a socket using MAC address from Embedded FPGA

Tags: c, sockets, embedded, protocols, fpga

I have a small FPGA that needs to communicate with a C program running on a Ubuntu Machine via ethernet. The FPGA is too small to use TCP etc. I can send frames and pick them up in wireshark using just the MAC address of the ethernet port but to communicate with the C I need to use a RAW Socket however in creating the socket it needs a protocol value, is there any protocol that would allow me to communicate solely using the MAC address.

The frames have the following structure

```
Destination MAC address
Source MAC address
Protocol - 0x55aa
Data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `PF_PACKET` instead of `PF_INET` then your `0x55aa` value is your protocol number:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>

packet_socket = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, ntohs(0x55aa));
```